# Headphones are recognized as an input device

Tags: settings, sound

My headphones are currently recognized as an input device, how can I make them an output device? The speakers and the headphones microphone are recognized correctly.

Edit:
I'm currently on a desktop pc. The devices are connected by 3 separate jacks. Two of them seem to work, except for the third one which is listed as a input device.

[image: Screenshot of sound settings]

Edit2:
The blue jack is where I plug in my headphones. The pink one is used for microphone and the green one is used for speakers.
[image: A picture of the three jacks]

Comment: Are they both connected through USB? Separate cables or one single jack connector?

Comment: I'm on a pc and there are 3 jacks. One for speakers, one for headphones and one for the microphone. From left to right I have: (pink) microphone - works, (green) speakers - works, (gray) headphones doesn't work, unless I plug out the speakers from the green jack and plug in the headphones.

Comment: Can you take a picture of your audio inputs (with cables disconnected)? That might help understand your soundcard configuration.

Comment: @saintjules Thank you for the response! I attached the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your headphones are being recognized as an input device, because, according to the official [PC system design guide color-coding sheme for connectors and ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_System_Design_Guide#Color-coding_scheme_for_connectors_and_ports), you are plugging them into a line-in jack. So, everything works as expected :)

However, it is possible to retask the jacks of your sound device with `HDAjackretask`, which is part of the package `alsa-tools-gui` in the official repositories.

[image: HDAjackretask]

HDAjackretask is an experimental application, it may not work, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your headphones "are not working" because you are plugging them into the wrong jack. The correct jack for them is indeed the green one, as you have confirmed, too. The blue one, on the contrary, is a Stereo Line-in, that is why it is recognized as such. [Here](http://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/sound-card-color-code.php) is a simple explanation of standard audio jacks on a soundcard.

If you want to keep your speakers plugged into the green output, you have to find an alternative output. Don't you have any others maybe on the front side?